# Is there a way to avoid from the mouse when moving a user input slider to highlight the html embed element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, velo

This is my site now. nothing much there yet. only the google map and a user input slider.  if you will move the slider left/right and while dragging it you drag the mouse up/down you will see that it's like selecting highlighting the map.

https://rhodan.wixsite.com/my-site-1

The problem is when I'm moving the slider to the left or to the right if the mouse is a bit leaving the slider up or down it's highlighting the html element.

it's like when dragging the mouse on the slider to change the slider value sometimes it's also highlighting the html element.

[image: the mouse is moving the slider at the bottom and the html element or the page it self is highlighting.]

I tried john solution and added to my html embed code in wix the answer part to the bottom:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google Maps Api</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
  
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
  
<style>#map
    {
        width: 1500px;
        height:900px;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
    
    #map.fullscreen {
        position: fixed;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
      }</style>
  
<script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&v=weekly&language=he"
      defer
    ></script>

<script>let map;

    function initMap() {
        // The location of Uluru
        const uluru = { lat: 32.1582615544072, lng: 34.89155037133181 };
    
        // The map, centered at Uluru
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: uluru,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          fullscreenControl: true,
          options: {
    gestureHandling: 'greedy'
  }
        });

        // Create the DIV to hold the control.
      const centerControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
      // Create the control.
      const centerControl = createCenterControl(map);
      // Append the control to the DIV.
      centerControlDiv.appendChild(centerControl);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(centerControlDiv);
    
        const chicago = { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 };
    
        /**
         * Creates a control that recenters the map on Chicago.
         */
        function createCenterControl(map) {
          const controlButton = document.createElement("button");
        
          // Set CSS for the control.
          controlButton.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
          controlButton.style.border = "2px solid #fff";
          controlButton.style.borderRadius = "3px";
          controlButton.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
          controlButton.style.color = "rgb(25,25,25)";
          controlButton.style.cursor = "pointer";
          controlButton.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
          controlButton.style.fontSize = "16px";
          controlButton.style.lineHeight = "28px";
          controlButton.style.borderLeftWidth = "8px";
          controlButton.style.margin = "8px 8px 22px 0";
          controlButton.style.padding = "0 5px";
          controlButton.style.textAlign = "center";
          controlButton.textContent = "Center Map";
          controlButton.title = "Click to recenter the map";
          controlButton.type = "button";
          
          // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
          controlButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            map.setCenter(chicago);
          });
          return controlButton;
        }
    
        const rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map,
            bounds: {
                north: uluru.lat - 0.005,
                south: uluru.lat + 0.005,
                west: uluru.lng - 0.005,
                east: uluru.lng + 0.005,
            },
          });
    }
    
      window.initMap = initMap;</script>
  
  <script>function dontSelectAnything(evt) {
       evt.preventDefault();
    }
        
    const slider = document.getElementById("slider1");

    slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (evt) => {
      document.addEventListener('selectstart', dontSelectAnything);
    }

    slider.addEventListener('mouseup', (evt) => {
        document.removeEventListener('selectstart' dontSelectAnything);
    }</script>

    <input id="slider1" type="range">

    <p>You should not be able to select me when you click above slider and drag the mouse around</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the part of the solution:

```
<script>function dontSelectAnything(evt) {
           evt.preventDefault();
        }
            
        const slider = document.getElementById("slider1");
    
        slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (evt) => {
          document.addEventListener('selectstart', dontSelectAnything);
        }
    
        slider.addEventListener('mouseup', (evt) => {
            document.removeEventListener('selectstart' dontSelectAnything);
        }</script>
    
        <input id="slider1" type="range">
    
        <p>You should not be able to select me when you click above slider and drag the mouse around</p>
```

but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1):

On mouse down you need to do something like:

```
// add event
document.addEventListener('selectstart', dontSelectAnything);
```

and on mouse up you need to remove it

```
// remove event
document.removeEventListener('selectstart' dontSelectAnything);
```

finally... add this function

```
function dontSelectAnything(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
}
```

the evt.prevenyDefault() prevents the browser from carrying out the default selectstart behavour which prevents any selection from working.

Proof of concept...

```js
function dontSelectAnything(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
}
    
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll("[data-testid='track']");

sliders.forEach( (s) => {
  s.addEventListener('mousedown', (evt) => {
    document.addEventListener('selectstart', dontSelectAnything);
  });

  s.addEventListener('mouseup', (evt) => {
      document.removeEventListener('selectstart', dontSelectAnything);
  });
});
```

```html
<input data-testid="track" type="range">

<p>You should not be able to select me when you click above slider and drag the mouse around</p>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the problem is still remains.  I edited my question with what I tried.

Comment: Put the javascript <script> code after the HTML otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: it's creating a new gray slider and it's working on that one but how do I make it to work on the slider I have from wix? the slider I dragged in its title name is slider1.  and in your code solution in both places in the id and getElementById in both places I changed it to "slider1" but still it's creating a new slider. how can I apply the code to the existing slider?

Comment: I've updated proof of concept code. You don't need the <input data-testid="track" type="range"> from my proof of concept inside your wix content. Make sure you copy all the code over again because there are minor changes here and there compared to the original code. If it doesn't work for you then try looking at the console for errors and see if anything appearing there.